# problem with deleting reference of entity from jointable

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I have two Entities in my Spring Project : Books and Users .. and i have One JoinTable from these tables: users_books .. the relationShip between them is `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` ... now if i delete One Book ..  how i can delete its reference from the joinedTable that created automaticly after run the program ?
in the Book Entity :

```
 @JsonBackReference    
 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)    
 private User user;
```

in the User Entity :

```
@JsonManagedReference    
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)    
private List<Book> books;
```

Comment: Patrick .. thank you for fix editing ..